# perl extract substrings between 2 delimiters

Tags: regex, string, perl, split, csv

I have a file similar to one below.

```
Jobs                             |Status |Wait Reason |Wait Local |Wait Remote |Running |Passing |Failing |Skipped |Failures 
--------------------------------- ------- ------------ ----------- ------------ -------- -------- -------- -------- ---------
build1                           |FAILED |            |           |            |        |      8 |     5  |        |         
build2                `          |PASSED |            |           |            |        |      2 |        |        |         
build3                           |PASSED |            |           |            |        |      6 |        |        |
```

I need to extract the substrings between the delimiter **'|'**. I tried using the below regex

`$row=~ s/ //g;
(@substrings)= $row =~ /|(.*?)\|/g;`

the result was

```
0 :
1 : build1
2 :
3 : FAILED
4 :
5 :
6 :
7 :
8 :
..
```

I also used the split function `split '|',$row;` but it returned data as

```
b
u
i
l
d
1


|
F
..
```

I'm trying to extract the following data.

```
$substrings[0]=build1
$substrings[1]=FAILED
$substrings[2]=(null)
```

and so on.

How to extract the substrings?

Comment: You forgot to escape the first pipe `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Maddy and sebnukem mentioned, split is the answer.  Using just regex's for this is doable, but more complicated because of the lack of pipes (`|`) at the beginning and end of your lines.  Here's a script that reads through your data file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $line (<>) {
#   print $line;
    chomp($line);
    next unless $line =~ /\|/; # only try lines with pipes in them
    my @fields = split(/\s+\|/,$line);
    print Dumper(\@fields);
}
```

Here is an example of running it:

```
chicks$ cat data.txt | ./proc_data.pl 
$VAR1 = [
          'Jobs',
          'Status',
          'Wait Reason',
          'Wait Local',
          'Wait Remote',
          'Running',
          'Passing',
          'Failing',
          'Skipped',
          'Failures '
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'build1',
          'FAILED',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '      8',
          '     5',
          '',
          '         '
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'build2                `',
          'PASSED',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '      2',
          '',
          '',
          '         '
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'build3',
          'PASSED',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '      6',
          '',
          '',
          '        '
        ];
```

Note that the `split` puts the regex in slashes, not quotes and the backslash must be escaped: `\|`.  I also included a `\s+` to trim spaces from the right side of the results.  A `\s+` on the other side of the regex would get the left side spaces like in `'     6'`.  If you want it to match 0 or more spaces you should use the `*` instead of `+` in those places.

Comment: Useless use of `cat` here. The diamond operator does the same thing when `@ARGV` contains a list of filenames.

Comment: `\s+` did the trick. I was trying to match start and end and extract string in between.

Comment: Also, the first argument to `split()` absolutely can be a string---in fact, there are a couple special cases for the empty string (`''`) and a string containing a single space (`' '`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the split function. Below is one example where delimeter is space, you can replace it with '|' pipe symbol.

```
my $str = "ab cd ef gh ij";
my @words = split / /, $str;
```

Comment: This would turn `build1        | ` into `"build1", "", "", "", "", "", ...` with one field for each space. You want `' '` -- a single literal space. Or `/ +/`, or `/\s+/`.